# Mocking IStringLocalizerFactory in C# throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I'm trying to write a test for a service that uses IStringLocalizerFactory to translate strings. All of the translations are in a single Resource file. I cannot seem to get the Mock for it to work, as it always throws a NullReferenceException. When debugging, it shows that _localizer is null. When I remove the localizer logic completely, the test succeeds.

Code I'm trying to test:

```
        private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

        public EventService(IEventRepository eventRepository, IMemberEventRepository memberEventRepository, IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
        {

            this._eventRepository = eventRepository;
            this._memberEventRepository = memberEventRepository;
            this._localizer = factory.Create(typeof(Resource));
        }

        public async Task CreateEventRegistrationAsync(MemberEvent entity)
        {
            if (await this._memberEventRepository.GetMemberEvent(entity.EventId, entity.MemberId) != null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(_localizer["This member already participates in this event."].Value);
            }

            await this._memberEventRepository.CreateAsync(entity);
        }
```

My tests:

```
        private Mock<IStringLocalizerFactory> _stringLocalizerFactoryMock = new Mock<IStringLocalizerFactory>();

        public EventServiceTests()
        {
            _service = new EventService(_eventRepoMock.Object, _memberEventRepoMock.Object, _stringLocalizerFactoryMock.Object);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task CreateEventRegistrationAsync_ShouldThrowArgumentException_WhenMemberAlreadyRegisteredForEvent()
        {
            int eventId = 456;
            int memberId = 123;

            _stringLocalizerFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create(typeof(Resource)))
                .Returns(() => new StringLocalizer<Resource>(_stringLocalizerFactoryMock.Object));

            MemberEvent registration = new MemberEvent
            {
                EventId = eventId,
                MemberId = memberId
            };

            _memberEventRepoMock.Setup(x => x.GetMemberEvent(eventId, memberId))
                .ReturnsAsync(registration);
            
            await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(async () => await _service.CreateEventRegistrationAsync(registration));
        }
```

Comment: Where does it throw the exception exactly? The test code looks like you setup the factory correctly. From examining the subject under test I see that `_localizer["This member already participates in this event."].Value` will throw a null exception because `_localizer[...]` was not setup and thus fail when `.Value` is invoked.

Comment: Ik mis een beetje tijd om het uit te zoeken. Maar in de (eigen, zeer cryptische) nota's die ik had gemaakt bij een soortgelijk probleem staat er: Uitvoerige documentatie is gevonden in de Asp.net core-code zelf, zie repositoryReferenceCode: aspnetcore-main. Waarbij ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory werd gevonden als enige concrete klasse die IlocalizerFactory toepast voor het concreet aanmaken van de factory. Ik heb geen flauw benul of dit je ergens kan helpen, baat het niet, dan schaadt het niet ... .

Comment: @qqtf - I understand that based on the name of the poster that you’ve worked out that he’s Dutch and think it would be easier to write in that language. However, stack overflow is an English site and recommends that everything is done in English as more people will be able to help. Your comment is useless to the majority of the community.

Answer (score 0):

From examining the subject under test I see that

```
_localizer["This member already participates in this event."].Value
```

will throw a null exception because `_localizer[...]` was not setup and thus fail when `.Value` is invoked.

Consider mocking a `IStringLocalizer<T>` so that it can be setup to behave as expected when the test is invoked.

```
//...

var localizer = new Mock<IStringLocalizer<Resource>>();

localizer
    .Setup(_ => _[It.IsAny<string>()])
    .Returns(string key => new LocalizedString(key, key));

_stringLocalizerFactoryMock
    .Setup(_ => _.Create(It.IsAny<Type>()))
    .Returns(() => localizer.Object));

//...
```